# Oracle Apex using Mailto with Variable page date

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, mailto

I'm trying to use a button which opens an email with pre populated information. But require variables from page elements.
 so for example P45_DATE get the update date and P45_DATA gets the data.

I tried different element identifiers  like : , & or @. but if used nothing gets return upto the first identifier.

```
mailto:test@test.com&cc=someoneelse@test.com?Subject=Extension report for &P45_DATE. &body=Please see Extension below. &P45_DATA
```

Is this even possible

Oracle 11g2
apex 4.2.5.00.08

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where you are defining this string and if you want client or session state values.
If as part of JavaScript expression, you might use something like:

```
'mailto:test@test.com&cc=someoneelse@test.com?Subject=Extension report for '+$v('P45_DATE')+'&body=Please see Extension below. '+$v('P45_DATA')
```

Bear in mind this isn't escaping the data. Also check to see if any errors are appearing in the JavaScript console.